# How to set fragment duration for azure media services Adaptive Streaming preset?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Azure media services provide standard preset called Adaptive Streaming for asset encoding. I'm using output for HLS streaming. It looks like default fragment size is 6 seconds but I would like to change this to 2. I was unable to find how to do this anywhere in the docs.

Note: I know that it is possible to create custom preset but that looks like an overkill and instead I'm looking at the ways to configure an existing preset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Adaptive Streaming" preset does not expose any parameters, and therefore you cannot change the GOP duration. You could use a custom preset as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-custom-mes-presets-with-dotnet). However, for on-demand streaming, our dynamic packaging service will pack 5 GOPs into one HLS segment (giving you a segment length of 10 seconds in such cases).

Can you share more details offline (to amshelp@microsoft.com) about why you need shorter duration HLS segments for VoD scenarios?

Comment: I sent more details to the email address

Comment: @Anil Murching, i'm finding more and more posts where you guys encourage your users to email you offline. Why not continue the conversation publicly so other users can benefit?